# Cannot see all available wireless networks?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking, troubleshooting

There are two wireless networks setup in my office, a primary one and a backup. Plus there are few other wireless networks nearby. However, Windows (XP SP3) has ceased to show other available wireless networks when I am **connected**. I frequently have to switch networks every now and then and for that I have to go to `Wireless Network Connection`'s  properties, change the order of networks and `Repair` the connection... to much time consuming. Can anyone tell me why I can't see all available wireless network connections? Here are the screen caps:

View Available Wireless Networks Window

[image: View Available Wireless Networks Window]

Wireless Network Connection Properties -- Notice two networks that are available, up and running

[image: Wireless Network Connection Properties]

Comment: Ummmm - superuser.com would be a much more appropriate place for this question.

Comment: have you tried updating your wireless driver? this might help with that. Also have you tried disabling it and restarting it? give these a try.

Comment: the "Preferred Networks" list isn't a list of the networks Windows sees, it's a list of networks Windows has connected to at some time in the past.

Comment: Maybe it's because Win XP isn't supported by MS anyymore? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that wifi network is around you and yet, you can't see it in wifi list but if you manually write SSID of AP or change the preference of WiFi networks it connects, then you can check that:

1. Access Point is broadcasting beacon frames.
2. You have recent wireless drivers installed.